# Implement SSO using SAML in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, tableau-api

Am very new to saml and went through some tutorials,

But am unable to start it from the point.

i have a web mvc web application. Need to implement SSO because am using a tableau api which prompts login.

What else i needed.

Need to buy a IDP. how to set up my web app a service provider.

please lead me. Any step by step description will be great.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to buy anything - there are open source IDP.

e.g. [SimpleSAMLphp](http://simplesamlphp.org/).

Using this as an IDP, [Configure IDP](http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-idp)

[Tableau set up](http://downloads.tableausoftware.com/quickstart/feature-guides/saml.pdf)

So you export the metadata from Tableau - this is the sp.xml that simpleSAML requires. (Step 2 in the document).

Then you export the metadata from simpleSAML - this is the idp.xml Tableau requires. (Step 3 in the document).